# Message factory

Tags: swift, factory-method

Today I thought about Factory Design Pattern in Swift, and I do an implementation with Extension.

My post is about if anyone have any observation or issue about this implementation violate any convention about Factories? Can I do this way?

I did it because I thought the statics function in my object not smell good, and for who will do maintenance it will confuse, and because this I split to Extension.

```
    let kToastMessageTurnType:String = "kToastMessageTurnType";
    let kWhoStartTheGameMessageType:String = "kWhoStartTheGameMessageType";

    class ToastMessage {

        private var gameState:GameState;

        private(set) var message:String = "";
        private(set) var isFoul:Bool = false;

        init(gameState:GameState, type:String, isFoul:Bool)
        {
            self.gameState = gameState;
            self.isFoul = isFoul;

            self.message = processMessage(type)
        }

        private func processMessage(type:String)->String
        {
            let textLocalized:TextLocalized;

            switch type
            {
            case GSFoulTypeBallEightPocketedInBreakShot:
                textLocalized = TextStartedIncorrectly(playersInfo: self.gameState);
            case GSFoulTypeBreakAtLeastFourBumpers:
                textLocalized = TextStartedIncorrectly(playersInfo: self.gameState);
             case kToastMessageTurnType:
                textLocalized = TextTurnMessage(playersInfo: self.gameState);
             case kWhoStartTheGameMessageType:
                textLocalized = TextWhoStartMessage(playersInfo: self.gameState);   
            default:
                return "";
            }

            return textLocalized.text
        }
    }
```

```
    //Factory from ToastMessage
    extension ToastMessage
    {
        class func getFoulToastMessage(type:String)->ToastMessage
        {
            return ToastMessage(gameState: GameState.shared, type: type, isFoul: true);
        }

        class func getNotifyTurnMessagetMessage()->ToastMessage
        {
            return ToastMessage(gameState: GameState.shared, type: kToastMessageTurnType, isFoul: false);
        }

        class func getWhoStartTheGameMessage()->ToastMessage
        {
            return ToastMessage(gameState: GameState.shared, type: kWhoStartTheGameMessageType, isFoul: false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't recommend these string constants at all.  We should be using an `enum`.  Even if your `enum` is still string backed (which it doesn't appear that that'd be necessary), it's still going to be better overall to use an `enum`.

As a start, the `enum`, means that users can't simply pass any random value in.  The values they can select from are more clearly defined.  Auto-complete will give them a hint at their choices.

It's also more efficient.  Despite the `enum` being back by a string, the actual value you're passing around isn't a string at all.  The string is only ever accessed if you call `RawValue` on the `enum` value.  This means all your `enum` comparisons (and `switch` statements) are all more efficient.

But the most important thing about using an `enum` here is that it might completely eliminate the need for your factory methods extension.

`GameState` is apparently a singleton accessed via the `.shared` property.  You haven't provided enough context for me to take a stab at the idea of this being a singleton (maybe/probably unnecessary), but if it is a singleton, why does it need to be passed around, rather than just accessing it directly where ever it's needed?  That sort of defeats the point of a singleton.

Likewise, we're not provided enough information about `isFoul:` and what that's supposed to mean.

But the point is `GameState` can definitely be eliminated from the initializer.  And if we turn the `type` from a `String` to an `enum` with limited options, then the factory extension just seems completely unnecessary, because the `init` method is simple enough.

Comment: Your answer will be very important for my refactor in this code, Thanks @nhgrif.

Comment: In this case I can eliminate the Factory with Enuns, but use Factory with extension is a good way to do? What do you think about this implementation for Factory?

Comment: I don't think factory methods like this are particularly helpful in Swift.  Factory methods are nice in Objective-C when they eliminate `[[MyClass alloc] initWith...` and turn that into `[MyClass myClassWith...` but in Swift, I don't think we need nearly as many factory methods.

Comment: great observation, i didn't think about it... thanks again

Comment: @nhgrif I'm sorry, I am confused as to why this question was off topic based on the comment you left on SO. It appears to have multiple upvotes along with your answer being upvoted and accepted. I want to make sure I don't make incorrect recommendations going forward.

Comment: @Joe The question on SO was example code. When it was posted here in that format, it was closed (check question edit history). Also, you're welcome to join us in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: If you compare the edit history, you'll notice it's quite hard for me to post my answer with the originally posted example code.